Compute $\int_C\frac{z^{2011}}{z^{2011}+z^{2010}+z^{2009}+1}dz$ with two different answers

Compute $$\int_C\frac{z^{2011}}{z^{2011}+z^{2010}+z^{2009}+1}dz,$$
where $C$ is the circle $\vert{z}\vert=2$.

Solution 1 Firstly, we show that all roots of $$z^{2011}+z^{2010}+z^{2009}+1$$ lie inside $\vert{z}\vert<2$:
If there exists some root that lies in $\vert{z}\vert\geq 2$, then since $1+\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{z^{2011}}=0$, we have $$1=\left\vert{\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{z^{2011}}}\right\vert\leq \left\vert{\frac{1}{z}}\right\vert+\left\vert{\frac{1}{z^2}}\right\vert+\left\vert{\frac{1}{z^{2011}}}\right\vert\leq \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2^{2011}}<1. (\Rightarrow\Leftarrow)$$
Thus, we can write it as $$\int_{\vert{z}\vert=R}\frac{z^{2011}}{z^{2011}+z^{2010}+z^{2009}+1}dz(R>2)$$
\begin{align*}
 \int_C\frac{z^{2011}}{z^{2011}+z^{2010}+z^{2009}+1}dz&=\int_C1-\frac{1}{z}+\frac{z^{2009}-z+1}{z^{2011}+z^{2010}+z^{2009}+1}dz
\end{align*}
Since $$\left\vert\frac{z^{2009}-z+1}{z^{2011}+z^{2010}+z^{2009}+1}\right\vert\leq \frac{R^{2009}+R+1}{R^{2011}-R^{2010}-R^{2009}-1}\to 0,$$
the integral is equal to $-2\pi i$.
Solution 2 Firstly, we show that all roots of $$z^{2011}+z^{2010}+z^{2009}+1$$ lie inside $\vert{z}\vert<2$:
If there exists some root that lies in $\vert{z}\vert\geq 2$, then since $1+\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{z^{2011}}=0$, we have $$1=\left\vert{\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{z^{2011}}}\right\vert\leq \left\vert{\frac{1}{z}}\right\vert+\left\vert{\frac{1}{z^2}}\right\vert+\left\vert{\frac{1}{z^{2011}}}\right\vert\leq \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2^{2011}}<1. (\Rightarrow\Leftarrow)$$
Thus, \begin{align*}
 \int_C\frac{z^{2011}}{z^{2011}+z^{2010}+z^{2009}+1}dz&=\int_C1-\frac{z^{2010}+z^{2009}+1}{z^{2011}+z^{2010}+z^{2009}+1}dz
\end{align*} and $$\left\vert\frac{z^{2010}+z^{2009}+1}{z^{2011}+z^{2010}+z^{2009}+1}\right\vert\leq \frac{R^{2010}+R^{2009}+1}{R^{2011}-R^{2010}-R^{2009}-1}\to 0 ,$$
the integral is equal to to $0$.
I know that the second one is wrong, but I couldn't find the mistake myself. Thanks in advance!

@Pranay $\vert z^{2011}+z^{2010}+z^{2009}+1 \vert\geq \vert z^{2011} \vert-\vert z^{2010}+z^{2009}+1\vert$ and then use the induction.

Thanks, I realized as soon as I posted my now-deleted comment.

Perhaps I am misremembering, but shouldn't the integrand fall off as faster than $1/R$ for the integral to vanish? This is the case in the first solution, but not in the second solution.

@Pranay I used that $\frac{R^{2010}+R^{2009}+1}{R^{2011}-R^{2010}-R^{2009}-1}\sim \frac{1}{R}\quad \text{and}\quad \lim_{R\to\infty} \frac{1}{R}=0$

But that's just the integrand. The integral has an additional factor of $2\pi R$ coming from the perimeter of the circle.

For a more thorough explanation, see @Justauser's answer below.

In any case, to avoid discussing the behaviour of the function at infinity, you could substitute $z=1/u$ and work around the origin. That should be more straightforward.

@Pranay I realized it. Thanks for your help!!

The second approach is problematic, becasue while the function approaches $0$, the integral doesn't necessarily. If the same logic applies, we would have $\int_C \frac{1}{z}dz = 0$, contradicting basic knowledge of complex analysis.
All we have is $|\int_C f(z)dz|\le \max_{z\in C}|f(z)|\cdot\operatorname{len}(C)$, and when $R$ approaches $\infty$, the length of $C$ also approaches $\infty$.
The first approach is essentially correct, however it's not just because $\frac{R^{2009}+\cdots}{R^{2011}+\cdots}$ approches $0$ as $R\rightarrow\infty$, but it depends on the fact that even with an extra $R$ growth (the length of $C$), $$\frac{R^{2009}+\cdots}{R^{2011}+\cdots}\cdot 2\pi R\rightarrow 0$$
(I didn't check the calculations though.)
